# What does the verb "borne" mean here? Is it used correctly?

Tags: meaning, verbs

The actor creates on the stage infinite sensations, feeling, or emotions that become the
emotions of the whole theatrical audience. Before they become the subject of the actor’s
embodiment, they were given a literary formulation, they were ***borne*** in the air, in social
consciousness (Vygotsky 1999b, p. 241)

Comment: It's only _approximately_ correct. _Borne_ is the past participle of the somewhat literary verb to _bear_: to carry. The **wind** certainly carries things: smells, sounds, paper bags, thistledown and so on. They are carried (or borne) _by_ or _on_ the wind. Or they might be borne up into the air by the wind, but the air doesn't usually bear them. I can't work out what the quotation means.

Comment: Btw, ,the quotation might make more sense if it said, "Before they become the subject of the actor’s embodiment, **or** were given a literary formulation..."

Comment: It is being used poetically to say “picked up and carried by/into”